# Changing position of canvas element parent div in css distorts drawing

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a simple canvas drawing program that works perfectly.

But when I want to use it on my webpage I have to position it. I need canvas element to be inside 1 div element and i need to position that div element in css. When I do change position of parent div element my canvas window moves regularly but when I try to draw, mouse position of my cursor is not matching line on the screen.

I would like to know how to solve this problem and how to position my canvas window correctly where I want.

Here is canvas program that works(color buttons are not positioned well but nevermind).
    HjD7e -> jsfiddle id
And here is the one that is messed up(cursor position is not matching)
    S6Dhe -> jsfiddle id

Comment: Please provide the least amount of code that illustrates your problem

Comment: I added 2 examples on jsfiddle. One working and other dont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are now offsetting multiple elements, you'll need to take the new positions into account. Seeing as you are positioning the parent container, it might be easier to put all your positioning there and remove the extra positioning from the canvas itself. Using:

```
#contain{
    position:absolute;
    top:300px;
    left:500px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px
    }
```

instead. From there, change the code getting the positions to:

```
contain = document.getElementById('contain');
currX = e.clientX - contain.offsetLeft + window.scrollX;
currY = e.clientY - contain.offsetTop + window.scrollY;
```

also accounting for scrolling in the window.

The working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xAFnp/1/). (Caveat, only tested in Firefox)

Comment: Thx for answer that was the thing i was looking for. I could not find soultion on internet everyone was saying it can onl be done with fabric js.